Horizontal image inside a PageView
Thank you for having me. My question is quite genuine. I've been working with SwiftUI for about 6 months, and this is something I have always struggled to understand how to do properly. How exactly do you correctly place vertical and horizontal images in a PageView? The problem I have is that whenever I upload a horizontal photo from my phone, it stutters when navigating in the PageView. This surely has something to do with aspectRatio. Vertical images are fine. You can reproduce this by adding a vertical and a horizontal image from your phone to the Asset. Here is my code and a clip showing the problem. Thank you.
Here is a video link showing the issue:  https://streamable.com/ppjner
import SwiftUI

struct PageView: View {
    
    let images: [String] = ["image1", "image2", "picture3", "image4"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView {
                ForEach(images, id: \.self) { image in
                    Image(image)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .clipped()
                }
            }
            //            .frame(width: 350, height: 350)
            .containerRelativeFrame(.vertical) { size, axis in
                size * 0.5
            }
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
            .tabViewStyle(.page)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    PageView()
}


This is happening because the image is not clipped until the new page is in position.
Try showing the image as an overlay over Color.clear. Then move the .clipped() modifier to after the overlay:
ForEach(images, id: \.self) { image in
    Color.clear
        .overlay {
            Image(image)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
        }
        .clipped()
}


You could also consider changing the scaling depending on the aspect ratio and using scaled-to-fit for wide images, instead of scaled-to-fill. ViewThatFits can be used for this, see my answer to Image is being rendered with 1/3 of screen width for details.

@OsmanM.You're welcome, thanks for accepting the answer. I think the reaction to your post has been rather harsh. However, another time, I would suggest you try to attach an animated gif to the post, instead of linking to another site. There are free web services that can be used to convert a screen recording (mp4) to a gif. It would also help to provide example images that can be used to reproduce the problem. The easier it is to reproduce a problem, the more help you are likely to get to solve it.
